# NSArray causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, arrays, memory-management, nsarray

I declare an NSArray in one class like this:

`.h`

```
@interface HTTP : NSObject {
NSArray *listOfProfiles;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *listOfProfiles;
```

`.m`

```
-(id) init {
if ((self = [super init])) {
    listOfProfiles = [[NSArray alloc] init];
}
return self;
}

-(void) someMethod {
...
    case GET_LIST_OF_PROFILES:
        listOfProfiles = [result componentsSeparatedByString:@"^-^"];
        NSLog(@"first break: %@",[listOfProfiles objectAtIndex:0]);
        break;
...
}
```

I can access it here just fine, then when I try to access it in another class after creating an object I receive the error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and the debugger goes to main.m:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
http = [[HTTP alloc] init];
[http createProfileArray];
profileListDelay = [[NSTimer alloc] init];
profileListDelay = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(profileListSelector) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

- (void) profileListSelector 
{
if (http.activityDone)
{
    // http.listofprofiles mem leak?
    for (int i = 0; i < http.listOfProfiles.count; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",[http.listOfProfiles objectAtIndex:i]);
    }
    [profileListDelay invalidate];
    profileListDelay = nil;
}
}
```

I'm thinking it's a memory issue maybe, but I could be completely wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a memory issue

It is in `someMethod`

```
-(void) someMethod {
...
    case GET_LIST_OF_PROFILES:
        listOfProfiles = [result componentsSeparatedByString:@"^-^"];
        NSLog(@"first break: %@",[listOfProfiles objectAtIndex:0]);
        break;
...
}
```

`componentsSeparatedByString:` returns an autoreleased object
Since you declared the array as a `retain` property, you should update it like so:

```
self.listOfProfiles = [result componentsSeparatedByString:@"^-^"];
```